Unable to seal a partially inset vessel sink
I am installing an attractive halfway between a vessel sink and an undermount called a semi-recessed sink.  There are two tiers to the sink: the portion above the countertop and an inset area that rests below.

Here is a side view after having placed the countertop (and with some of the plumbers putty bead showing on the left side):

An issue I face is sealing the countertop. The installation instructions stipulate a ring of plumbers putty where the sink rests on the countertop.  While that's all well and good if the cut is almost absolutely perfect, mine is not: it varies by up to about 3/16 of an inch.  Plumbers putty is meant to seal a minuscle crack not act as spackling:

Another concern is that this required a lot of plumbers putty. I have two more sinks and would rather not that much more of the stuff.   So another approach to sealing this would be preferred.  Are rectangular flexible gaskets sold that might do the trick? Other ideas?

It is not at all unusual that the bottom of sinks are not perfectly flat, straight and level. This more apparent when they are mated to a perfectly flat surface such as a countertop. (3/16" is not too bad.)
The usual method of sealing the gaps is with caulk.  Plumbers putty is good too, but the appearance is less than attractive from the front side. For this reason most plumbers and counter top technicians use a generous amount of silicone caulk when installing the sinks.
A bead is applied to the surface that will be touching the counter. Have plenty of rags and solvent to clean the overage. Occasionally an additional bead must be applied after the initial installation of the sink and the drain is installed.

I had followed the installation instructions that specify plumbers putty. It is a tricky, time consuming and moderately expensive approach. Its efficacy is also not proven: I am skeptical.  It is is however already completed on the above sink. I had mentioned in my own answer that I am already planning to put a bead of silicone around the entire sink . Would you recommend doing so as is (and as I had planned) or removing the plumbers putty first and relying solely on the silicone?

I find plumbers putty the easy way to seal things.   For the future,  roll it into a "rope" and apply to whatever needs sealed.  I always finish the visible side of an edge with caulk. Truthfully I only use caulk, not putty. I can tell you if I was doing the job, yes I would scrape out a little bit of the putty and apply caulk and wipe it clean. The caulk gives a much better appearance.

This is not really a completely satisfactory "answer" but rather the best workaround I could come up with so far.

I raised the sink onto 2x4's
I repositioned the plumbers putty on the outside of the lip instead of around the inset piece



The sink was reset into the countertop hole
I ducked under the sink inside the cabinet and looked for daylight around the bottom edges of the sink lip. Yea I found a few spots.  So I manipulated the plumbers putty ring to cover those spots
The excess putty was removed from the topside of the sink. I will put a bead of silicone around the edges tomorrow



is your counter top flat? is the seating surface of the sink flat?

@Jasen. Yes it's flat. I specifically shimmed the countertop support lumber sections to level it.

Out of curiosity, what "seals" the putty?  Just pressing down on the sink?  I guess what I'm asking is: is there any kind of positive retention for the sink, or could someone lean on it and shift it out of position?

if everything is flat there will be no gap - use less putty.

@Jasen. The hole is a bit wide on one side so there is a gap between the inset portion and the mounted portion. I needed to move the putty to the lip of the latter.    The extra putty was not an issue, it scrapes right off and can be re-used.  I believe a seal was made but it was tricky.

@Huesmann. That's a very good point, I'm not actually sure and have asked the manufacturer their thoughts. The instructions seem to presume the installer would have made a laser accurate cut thus there would be no possibility of movement. I'm a humble home owner and have a 3/16" gap on one side due to a glitch in my cut.  It's not easily going to move due to the putty and silicone but it certainly could if knocked hard enough.

The other thing is sinks can often be fabbed within a dimensional tolerance, so even with a template, there's no way to even laser cut a hole that will be accurate.
